# get variable php error

Tags: php, get, simplexml

i am trying to load an xml file to php in order to display a table

```
// load SimpleXML
$d = $_GET['d'];
$books = new SimpleXMLElement('books.xml?cat=($d)', null, true);

echo <<<EOF
<table>
        <tr>
                <th>Title</th>
                <th>Author</th>
                <th>Publisher</th>
                <th>Price at Amazon.com</th>
                <th>ISBN</th>
        </tr>

EOF;
foreach($books as $book) // loop through our books
{
        echo <<<EOF
        <tr>
                <td>{$book->title}</td>
                <td>{$book->author}</td>
                <td>{$book->publisher}</td>
                <td>\${$book->amazon_price}</td>
                <td>{$book['isbn']}</td>
        </tr>

EOF;
}
echo '</table>';
```

**i am unable to get the Get variable return any data.hope you can help me.**

Comment: Does it even contain any data?

Comment: `$books = new SimpleXMLElement('books.xml?cat='.$d, null, true);` (but you should do some sort of sanitize on variables you get from user side)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a single vs double quote issue.

Change

```
'books.xml?cat=($d)'
```

to

```
"books.xml?cat=($d)"
```

...and [read this](http://php.net/manual/en/book.strings.php) again. Properly.

Answer (score 0):

At the very least `'books.xml?cat=($d)'` is not expanded. You need to use double quotes.